# VMware - Minix 3 - pkgin error

Tags: vmware, minix, vmware-player

I have set up Minix 3.3.0 on VMware 12.5.2

Ubuntu 16.04, Linux 4.4.8

When I try running

`# pkgin update`

I get an error saying

`pkgin: Can't open database /usr/var/db/pkgin/pkgin.db: unable to open database file: No such file or directory`

I have tried solution mentioned in [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936108/installing-vim-in-minix-3-1-8#), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34134039/unable-to-update-pkgin-database-in-minix) and [link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459372/minix-pkgin-error) but none of them worked for me.

This is for any command followed by `pkgin`

Comment: I had to run `setup` before anything. The problem is solved now.